# How to integrate the "shared with me" content into "My Drive" in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-for-desktop

In Dropbox the user can store an arbitrary folder shared with him at an arbitrary place. By default the folders shared with you land in the root, but they can be moved at any place you want within your Dropbox.

In Google Drive there is a separate area -- "Shared with me" -- where all the content shared with you is stored. And I dont'f find a way to move these folders into my My Drive area. And that is very inconvenient:

1. These folders don't get synchronized and cannot be accessed directly on the harddrive.
2. That destroys my data structure.

There are some articles on the Internet that describe approaches to get the shared folders into My Drive e.g., by changing the settings, but they all seem to be outdated.  At least, I have neither found a way to move the folders to My Drive (this option is grayed out), nor found the option "make available offline" for folders shared with me, nor found a general setting to integrate the "shared with me" content into My Drive.

The only possibility I see now, is to add a shortcut. But that doesn't solve the problem, that all the "shared with me" stuff is stored in one big "bucket".

**Is it possible / How to move / store the "shared with me" content into / in My Drive?**

Comment: Perhaps https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ might provide help?

Comment: In this case, the tag [tag:dropbox] should not be included because the question is not about Dropbox.

Comment: @Wicket - Questions about the desktop client are fine, questions about the service or the web application are out of scope, the tag when used for an in-scope is appropriate

Comment: @Ramhound I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Are you saying that this question is about how to use dropbox?

Comment: @Wicket - I thought you were saying the tag shouldn’t exist at all, however as the question is currently written, the question is about Google Drive as a service not the desktop client. The entire question isn’t appropriate for Super User (in my opinion) for that reason. My previous comment was applicable to both the Dropbox and Google Drive tag.

Answer (score 2):

In the past, it was possible to "add" files owned by others to "My Drive," but they changed how files are handled, and now it's not possible.

Your options are the following:

1. Add a shortcut of the file share with you to "My Drive".
2. Make a copy of the file shared with you. This will add the copy to "My Drive".

Another possibility is to use Shared Drives, which requires someone to have a Google Workspace account of an edition that supports them.

Reference

- [Learn how shortcuts replace files & folders stored in multiple locations](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10864219?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

**My Solution to Keep Data Structure Intact:**

1. Right-click and choose download on the file(s) or folder(s) you select.
2. Download the files to your preferred location - this will be a .ZIP
   file you'll have to extract.
3. Download and extract the files in the structure you want to the
   location of your choosing.
4. Once your file structure is to your liking, upload to My Drive.

Now all your files are in their original structure, with their names intact, editable by you, and thus a copy owned by you. This is the only way I have found you can accomplish this without 3rd party apps.

When you create shortcuts, you can't directly edit them on My Drive. When you create copies, Google adds "Copy of" to the start of each file name and doesn't allow you to choose where the files are located, which will both affect your file structure and force you to rename all the files.